# Magento 2 How to get Category attribute value label

Tags: magento2, php, category, attributes

Magenot 2 How to get Category attribute value label.

This code is magenot 1 and this code work to get Category attribute value label:-

```
<?php $title = Mage::getSingleton('categorylandingpage/entity_attribute_source_landingpageproducts')->getOptionText($mojoHelper->getCurrentCategory()->getCategoryLpageProducts()); ?>
```

I have Source Model File :-

```
<?php

namespace GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Landingpageproducts extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean implements ArrayInterface
{

    const VALUE_NO = 'lpage_no';
    const VALUE_NEW = 'lpage_new';
    const VALUE_FEATURED = 'lpage_featured';
    const VALUE_SALE = 'lpage_sale';

    protected $_options;

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::VALUE_NO, 'label' => __('No')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_NEW, 'label' => __('New Products')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FEATURED, 'label' => __('Featured Products')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_SALE, 'label' => __('Sale Products')]
        ];
    }

    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I want to convert above code in magenot 2.

Please Advice me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Do you want attribute value in phtml file in Magento 2?

Comment: No,i want to get attribute value label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below line in your phtml file, and replace `category_lpage_products` with your attribute code.

```
<?php
    $title = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $block->getCurrentCategory()->getCategoryLpageProducts(), 'category_lpage_products')
?>
```

**Update**

You can create one Helper file to get options like below

> app/code/GetSomeMojo/CategoryLandingPage/Helper/Data.php

Content for above file is..

```
<?php

namespace GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_categoryLandingPageProducts;

    public function __construct(
        \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Landingpageproducts $categoryLandingPageProducts
    ) {
        $this->_categoryLandingPageProducts = $categoryLandingPageProducts;
    }

    public function getAttributeOptionText($attributeOptionId)
    {
        return $this->_categoryLandingPageProducts->getOptionText($attributeOptionId);
    }
}
```

Now you can get attribute value in your phtml file using below code

```
<?php
    $categoryAttributeOptionId = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getData('category_lpage_products');
    $value = $this->helper('GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Helper\Data')->getAttributeOptionText($categoryAttributeOptionId);
?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: i have try but above get attribute value not a label

Comment: Do you have multi-select attribute? or simple text type?

Comment: i have Drop-down attribute.

Comment: Okay, so do you have source model for attribute options?

Comment: Yes,your are right. Please help how to get attribute value?

Comment: Okay can you please update you source model file's code

Comment: I have update my question Please check @Kishan Savaliya

Comment: Please check my updated answer, let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried? Any updates?

Comment: Yes, It is Work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please check this link and help me  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324550/85907

Comment: Please Help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325057/85907

Comment: Pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328962/85907