# How to Get Attributes options QTY in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, option

How to get Get Attributes specific options QTY in Magento 2.

Please Suggest me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: can you describe more, exactly what you want?

Comment: I have one configurable products and configurable products one attributes and I want attributes option qty. Please help how to achieve this.

Comment: You mean you want to check how many attribute option in attribute?